# Setting Solver Options for the Scip Solver in pyomo for MINLP Problem

Tags: python, pyomo, mixed-integer-programming, scip, ipopt

I am sorry if this question has been handled before but I have a problem implementing solver options for the Scip solver.
I am modelling a MINLP problem using the Scip solver for the MI part and ipopt for the NLP part. My problem is that solving the model the kernel freezes after a certain amount of iterations. I suspect the solver to be the problem, because it sometimes gets stuck when I look at the output with tee=True, the solver exceeds the limits I set before.

Please tell me, if I am mistaken with my formulation, I am a total beginner.
I use pyomo via anaconda, I get the problem in different environment, e.g. Colab and jupyter notebook

Thanks,
Michael

I try to cap the amount of iterations and the amount of time the solver takes with the following code, but it doesn#t seem to work:

```
solver = SolverFactory('scip', nlp_solver='ipopt')
solver = SolverFactory('scip')
solver.options['max_time'] = 30
solver.options['max_iter'] = 100
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question ... unfortunately an open still.

Possible workaround is to write all parameters into *scip.set* file and to put it into the folder where your python run the code. By default SCIP reads *scip.set* if it exists in the current folder...

And one more recommendation: use *with* operator:

```
with pyo.SolverFactory(path2scip + "scip") as opt:
   results = opt.solve(myPyomoModel, load_solutions=True, tee=True)
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35718297)